# Fragment won't load

Tags: android-fragments

So I tried making a drawer with a navigation drawer in it, and long story short, in the activity, the fragment which I tried to put inside doesn't load on runtime. The fragment code in my navdraweractivity.class looks like this:

```
Fragment fragment = new startingfragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit()
```

Part of my fragment layout looks like this:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".startingfragment">
```

Any possible reasons why and any possible solutions?

Comment: do you want to have drawer tab loaded by default when you open the activity? Is content_frame a FrameLayout? Here in your code everything is fine , you need to post more code of drawer layout and activity layout

Comment: Nvm, I solved it alrdy :-)